# Git - repository not found only after using git config credential.helper store

Tags: git, github

I'm encountering a very strange occurrence with Git.  Somebody made a private GitHub repository and shared permissions with me.

If I do the usual:

```
git clone https://github.com/OtherUsersName/RepoTitle.git
```

The repo clones as expected.  Then if I `cd` into the repo and do anything requiring remote permissions, ex.:

```
git pull
Username for 'https://github.com': [entered my username]
Password for 'https://MyGitHubAccount@github.com': [entered my password]
```

it works as expected, in this case it says:

```
Already up to date.
```

This is all as expected.  Then I save my password with:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

And do:

```
git pull
```

I get:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/OtherUsersName/RepoTitle.git' not found
```

Any idea what could cause this?

If in the repository after cloning I check `.git/config` it does not contain any password and if I check `~/.gitconfig` it contains my correct account username and password exactly as it should.

Comment: The password from `git credential-store` would be stored in `~/.git-credentials`, not `.git/config`.  What credentials are in that file?

Comment: Good call.  I deleted ~/.git-credentials, then repeated the above and it worked.  If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you have some other credentials in `~/.git-credentials`, which is the file that the `store` credential helper uses.  Since the credential helper will use any existing credentials instead of prompting, it should be sufficient to delete the offending lines (which are in URL format) from the file, or if you want, just delete the file altogether.

That should result in you being prompted for credentials and the `store` credential helper saving them into the file.